# Interesting issue with JavaScript object literals

Tags: javascript, json, object-literal

Try running this code:

```
var oObject = {"COL_SEQ":16,"SERVICE_CD":0.000000,"SERVICE_ID":0.000000,"COL_NAME":"","COL_OPTION":"nosort nofilter","COL_CLASS":"REMOVE_PATIENT","COL_TYPE":"","COL_LABEL":"","COL_OPTION":""};

alert(oObject.COL_SEQ);
alert(oObject.COL_OPTION);
alert(oObject.COL_CLASS);
```

I would expect the 2nd alert to show "nosort nofilter", but it doesn't; it alerts a blank message.

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/zD7Wm/

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a second (empty) `COL_OPTION` at the end of the object, which overwrites your initial one.

If you take out the second one, your code works fine:

```
var oObject = {"COL_SEQ":16,"SERVICE_CD":0.000000,"SERVICE_ID":0.000000,"COL_NAME":"","COL_OPTION":"nosort nofilter","COL_CLASS":"REMOVE_PATIENT","COL_TYPE":"","COL_LABEL":""};
```

Comment: And, this is a good reason why one should NOT use code that extends beyond the screen boundary.  It's way harder to notice these types of errors.

Comment: Would you believe I've been looking at this for the past 45 minutes and didn't notice the second COL_OPTION? :)